# jQuery scrolling issues with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am having 2 issues with scrolling, i figured it would just be easier to ask them both in one post.

Before I ask, below is my jQuery code im having issues with.

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if(this.hash){
        $("#main").animate({
            scrollTop : $("h3[name="+this.hash.substr(1)+"]").position().top - 120
        },2000,"easeOutExpo");
    }
});
```

Situation: What I have going on in my page is basically i have a side menu with a couple lists. Each item in each list links to a anchor in my main div section, or my 'content' section. When a list item is clicked, the code above runs and it scrolls to one of the anchors.

Issue 1: When i click on a item in one of the lists, it scrolls down to a anchor which works just fine. But when that same item is clicked again, the main area scrolls back up to the top of the div. My thought to fix this was to check the current 'scrolled to' location of the div, and then not allow the code to run again if the location hadn't changed since the first click but i couldn't get that to work. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Issue 2: Again as stated above, when i click on a item in a list it scrolls down to a anchor. What i then want to be able to to is click on a different list item and have it scroll to that position. The problem is when i click on a different list item, it scrolls to some random position in the main div, positions i haven't even anchored yet. Can anyone explain how I can make it so i can scroll from anchor to anchor?

Note: Please respond by having issue 1 or issue 2 above your explanation so i know which one your referring to. Thanks

**EDIT:** Thanks to Roko's help i got it working. For future viewers here is the fiddle of a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TsUcc/3/ and below is what the finally jquery code looks like

```
$("a").click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(this.hash){

        var target = '#'+ this.hash.substr(1);
        var destination = $(target).offset().top - 10;

        $('#main').stop().animate({
            scrollTop : '+=' + destination
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/EyuGeG/4/edit)

**ISSUE 1:**

you probably use something like: `<a href="#goto">goto</a>` and you did not prevented the browser default behavior which is simply done by passing the **event** to the `click` handler like:

```
$("a").click(function( e ) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // .....
});
```

**ISSUE 2**

The HTMLelement `position` you're using is just a passive position of an element relative to it's positioned parent element.
which means that an element can have a position of ie: `30` even if it's at the bottom of your page.
To fix that use

```
offset().top
```

<sub>Also worth reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect</sub>

**ISSUE 3**

`H3` elements are **not** supposed to have a `name` attribute.
**Use an `ID` for that purpose.**
*Why?*
if you have a nice web and you have some sexy stuff at the bottom of your page, I can send a link to my friend by referencing your web page and the `ID` in a link like:

> example.com#bottomLady

and he'll get immediately my thoughts without the need to scroll your page all the way down.

Comment: Thank you for replying, sadly none of what you suggest has changed either issue :( I added in the preventDefault(); changed to offset().top and switched from using names to ids but none of it worked.

Comment: Yes i saw the demo and to be honest i'm kinda surprised as to the reason yours works and mine doesn't. Is it becouse i am scrolling a div and not the html/body?

Comment: I updated the post to show you what my code looks like now, thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply, that wasn't working either. i made a fiddle of what my page basically looks like so you can see kinda what im going for. sorry the html is a mess, becouse ive been trying a whole bunch of things to get this to work. http://jsfiddle.net/TsUcc/

Comment: There are menus on the side, if you click on them the lists will drop down. Each list corresponds with a header in the main section on the left. i didnt get the scrollTop to even work right away so i left it out cause i didnt want to keep you waiting.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TsUcc/1/  Here under the API's menu, use the java - SE and the jQuery list items and you can see what the problem is. if you click on one twice it brings you back up. and it acts wierd when you go from one to another.

Comment: Sorry i just ment to post my site to quickly show what i was trying to get at. this is a much simpler version but still gives me the same issues. Mind taking a look? i believe did all the things you suggested. http://jsfiddle.net/TsUcc/2/

Comment: @Snakeyesz in your specific example you need to use `+=` to do the appropriate math: http://jsbin.com/edUsAGe/1/edit

Comment: YES! thats exactly what i was looking for thank you. Unfortunately this created another issue because now it is not working when i have the -120 at the end like: '+=' + $(target).offset().top - 120 Do you know why this would happen, or can you let me know how you found the '+=' fix so i can look into it.

Comment: Nevermind that last comment, i simply set $(target).offset().top - 120 as a var called destination and did scrollTop: '+=' + destination. I will mark this question as answered. Thank you for all your help :D

Comment: I edited the post to show a working demo and the correct code. Also if you don't mind, can you tell me how you figured out the += fix? or where you read that at? If you dont feel like taking the time to explain, then dont worry about it, its no big deal im just curious. Thanks again

Comment: @Snakeyesz http://jsbin.com/EyuGeG/9/edit (Did not read it anywhere, was logic to use `+=` cause we need to ADD the new targeted H3 element offset --> to the current scrollTop position)