# Issue with jQuery scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm building a website for a friend and I want it to scroll on href clicks, that is easy, I managed to do it with smooth animation. But the problem is, when I load the page and click on the FIRST link, scrolling is not precise, and after I click on anything after Test1 is pressed, its not precise again.
Since it's hard for me to explain, ill post jsfiddle link so you can test it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.click').click(function(e){
   // prevent default action
  e.preventDefault();

  scrollToElement( $(this).attr('href'), 1000 );
});

    var scrollToElement = function(el, ms){
    var speed = (ms) ? ms : 600;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top-102
    }, speed);
}

});
```

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pxmfs78k/

How to test my problem:

Press any link first time, and then you will see that the div is not positioned where I wanted it to be, and if you press the same link again, it will position itself correctly, and after that there are no problems in clicking until you reload or press test1 link, the first one.

So any idea what might cause the problem?

And I read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750702/jquery-scrolling-issues-with-scrolltop thread and I couldn't fix my problem with the explanation given there.

Comment: I would suggest passing the specific ID of the element

Comment: It's because of the sticky nav. When the page loads it's not sticky but it is as soon as you start scrolling. I suggest you remove the sticky thing or you add a class to the body to know when it's sticky or not and you adjust your calculation accordingly. The problem is not your scrollTo script

Comment: Or just give a padding to the body when it's sticky. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're setting the nav to sticky, thus, removing it from the flow, and the whole content jumps up by 102px, to fix this, give the sticky class to the body instead of the nav and use padding to fight against it. http://jsfiddle.net/pxmfs78k/1/

CSS

```
body.sticky {
    padding-top: 102px;
}
body.sticky .nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;

    var stickyNav = function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
            $('body').addClass('sticky');

        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    };

    stickyNav();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        stickyNav();
    });
});



$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.click').click(function (e) {
        // prevent default action
        e.preventDefault();

        scrollToElement($(this).attr('href'), 1000);
    });

    var scrollToElement = function (el, ms) {
        var speed = (ms) ? ms : 600;
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(el).offset().top - 102
        }, speed);
    }

});
```

Comment: Yea, this worked, but before you replied to me I did it a bit different, I set nav to have "sticky" class all the time, and It worked. So your first reply helped me a lot, thank you very much.